# Login with gmail on my site using JavaScript & php

Tags: javascript, gmail

Login with Gmail on my site on the HTML page using javascript & PHP. The page will not be refreshed after login.
I am using this code.

```
<script>
var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
var CLIENTID = '<Client ID>';
var REDIRECT = 'url/'
var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
var TYPE = 'token';
var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' +   REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
var acToken;
var tokenType;
var expiresIn;
var user;
var loggedIn = false;
function login() {
    var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
    var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            console.log(win.document.URL);
            if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url = win.document.URL;
                acToken = gup(url, 'access_token');
                tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                win.close();
                validateToken(acToken);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }, 500);
}
function validateToken(token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: VALIDURL + token,
        data: null,
        success: function(responseText) {
            getUserInfo();
            loggedIn = true;
            $('#loginText').hide();
            $('#logoutText').show();
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
}
function getUserInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
        data: null,
        success: function(resp) {
            user = resp;
            console.log(user);
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
}
//credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
function gup(url, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\#&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
function startLogoutPolling() {
    $('#loginText').show();
    $('#logoutText').hide();
    loggedIn = false;
    $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
}
</script>
```

This code will redirect to anothe page but I want page will not be referesh. Only give the response in the form of (true, false) from server.
please give better solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure try to add display=popup variable to _url and check

Comment: Hi Venkatesh Bachu thanks for solution.  iwant more information Like users email there is any parameter to access

Comment: you will get users email/details with userinfo endpoint try sample at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow and refer https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#authenticationuriparameters for supported parameters